How to increase drift radius in the acceleration of a top-down micro car?
I am finishing programming the acceleration of a micro car in a top-level viewpoint which is based in the current angle. Each arrow key, when pressed, sets a target angle for the car, causing the car to rotate gradually.
For a reference frame:
$$
a = \text{current angle}
$$
$$
vx = sin(a) \times \text{move speed}
$$
$$
vy = -cos(a) \times \text{move speed}
$$
a central force is applied in $(vx, vy)$, resulting into a new $\text{car velocity} = (vx, vy)$.
Previous questions:

Compute vector for a 2D drift

However my drift simply does not appear to exist if the move speed is too low for that drift to exist. Is there a way to increase the drift radius without increasing the move speed?
Or apparently, how to apply perpendicular acceleration in 2D space?
Arrows (goes from the current angle to ...):

UP=0°
UP-LEFT=315°
UP-RIGHT=45°
DOWN-LEFT=225°
DOWN-RIGHT=135°
LEFT=270°
RIGHT=90°

The car moves and rotates simultaneously, and drifts while moving.
Explanatory pictures:



How does "current angle" relate to "target angle"? Does the car always move exactly in the direction it is pointing (no sideways component of motion)? If so, there is zero drift in the sense that people usually mean when they say a car is drifting. What is "drift radius"? What is a "central" force and how do you apply a force "in" a velocity vector?

@DavidK The car rotates from its current angle to a "target angle" when any arrow is pressed or combined (UP=0, UP-LEFT=270 and so on). The car moves to where the arrow points, but through drifts depending in the angle, as in the Flash game SharkBite Bay Adventure (runs slow in Ruffle Player). I'll try adding pictures to ease the explanation.

@DavidK Updated. I've a video too, but it's not very fluid so didn't want to show it.

If you look closely, I think you will find that you answered exactly none of the questions I asked in my previous comment. The only real information I see is a diagram that appears to show several steps of the motion of a car around an approximately semicircular turn arc, showing nothing particularly unusual, with a different circle (irrelevant as far as I can tell) superimposed on the diagram. Without any understanding of how the physics model of the game actually works, nobody will be able to help you.
